# Restrict Android Safe Mode on power button press

Tags: android

I'm in need to stop entering safe mode on my nexus 7 tablet, because I implemented an Kiosk based application simply overriding home screen. Once default home screen changed to my custom home screen, user not allowed to take reboot device for safe mode. Is there any possibility to implement these feature without changing firmware OS.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Huh. Didn't know about that. In any case, it's part of the power button menu, which is still outside the control of SDK applications.

Comment: The only thing you can really do there is to physically prevent the user from pressing the power button, for example, by placing the tablet in a locked bezel.

Comment: @323go what do mean locked bezel? I tried to implement OnKeyDown/dispatchKey Listener but it doesn't effect to work.

Comment: I mean a case which prevents the user from reaching the power button (and/or unplugging the tablet, for that matter).